# How to set the preferred ColorScheme of an SwiftUI app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, darkmode

In my app I would like to have a section in the settings where the user can set whether he prefers light, dark or system.
My question is simple but I can not find anything on the internet about it. How can I set the darkmode to these three values? I tried the following (example app, is working):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var systemDesign: ColorScheme = .light
    @State private var darkMode: Int = 0
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    private var preferredDesign: ColorScheme {
        print("preferredDesign used.")
        if darkMode == 1 {
            return .light
        } else if darkMode == 2 {
            return .dark
        } else {
            print("systemDesign is  \(systemDesign)")
            return systemDesign
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                HStack{
                    Text("Design")
                        .frame(maxWidth: 100, alignment: .leading)
                    Spacer()
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        Picker("Design Picker", selection: $darkMode) {
                            Text("System").tag(0)
                            Text("Hell").tag(1)
                            Text("Dunkel").tag(2)
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.top, 13)
                .padding(.bottom, 13)
            }
            Divider()
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
        .preferredColorScheme(preferredDesign)
        .onChange(of: colorScheme) { newColorScheme in
            print("ColorScheme has changed.")
            systemDesign = newColorScheme
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

So i have a Picker and set the value of preferredColorScheme to the value the computed Variable gives me for the specified value. when i toggle darkmode on the device the @State property should be set to the darkmode setting of the device. But this does not work properly. Has anyone an Idea how i can realize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modifier `preferredColorScheme` takes an argument of `ColorScheme?`. Returning nil will tell the view that no specific color scheme should be used and defaults to the system's theme.

So you don't need `systemDesign` anymore, and `preferredDesign` should now be:

```
private var preferredDesign: ColorScheme? {
    print("preferredDesign used.")
    if darkMode == 1 {
        return .light
    } else if darkMode == 2 {
        return .dark
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, that solves the problem and makes the whole code more clear